Concept of buffer between fopen() and open()
I've read C fopen vs open.
I know a difference between fopen() and open() is whether buffer used or not.
Regarding above article mentioned buffer, I thought:
1. Does buffer mean additional 1 page of MMU required while fopen() called?
Assume MMU is enabled and 1 page of MMU is 4K Bytes.
Even a file I'd like to read which is only 2 character(2 bytes + 1 EOF),
minimum additional cost of space is 1 page (4KB) while I call fopen() in my program.
However, I read file with open() (read): char buffer[3]; read(fd, buffer, 3)
It's means additional space cost only 3 bytes, right?
2. Low size content use open(), big size content use fopen()?
As stated above.

If a file I'd like to read which is a byte e.g. value of sensor(/dev/iio/sensor1), open() + read() is better choice than fopen() + fgets().

If a file I'd like to read which is a 4K image, then select fopen() + fgets()


Right?

Are you in a memory-constrained scenario or need to squeeze every bit of performance from your code? If it's no to both then don't bother with the details and just do whatever is convenient. If it's yes to either one, then measure first, analyze and discuss second.

I'd bet that under the hood, fopen uses open (at least on POSIX systems and other native methods on different platforms). Another difference would be, that fopen is C standard, where open is POSIX.

Both open and fopen use buffers. It's just that with open you pass a buffer as an argument, while fopen allocates the buffer on the heap and uses it implicitly. You can circumvent that and provide your own buffer to the specific FILE stream, if you need to. Search setvbuf if interested.
Also, stdio utilities are basically providing a more convenient wrapper for system calls for opening, reading and writing files. So, if you are using unix, fopen most certainly uses open underneath.
Sometimes, using system call directly can be a good thing. Sometimes not.
You didn't provide much info about what exactly you want to achieve.
Also, regarding fgets as far as I know, it does not return you the location of the string in the buffer - it copies the string and gives it to you. If you are worrying about memory consumption - you probably want to avoid this.
There is an amazing book called Advanced programming in Unix environment which has chapters on both kinds of I/O - io using system calls and io using stdio.h functions(and more). I'd recommend getting your hands on that book - it's really good and thorough.


Does buffer mean additional 1 page of MMU required while fopen() called?

Not necessarily. fopen() will allocate a buffer in memory using whatever mechanism it likes. Most likely it will malloc the space. The buffer size is not necessarily one page. It's just an implementation detail that you don't need to worry about on the whole.

Low size content use open(), big size content use fopen()?

I would suggest always using fopen() unless there are special circumstances that require the lower level call. fopen() is standard C and is therefore guaranteed to be supported by any compliant C implementation.
If you just want to open a file read a small fixed number of bytes and then close it, directly using the system calls will be faster, but the overhead introduced by using buffered IO is likely to be dwarfed by the time it takes for the operating system to get the bytes off the storage device (your milage may vary - benchmark it).
